# Configure gradle to use Class Data Sharing in Java 11

Tags: java, gradle, java-11

I try to add:

```
compileJava {
//disable compilation in a separate daemon process...should be faster?
options.fork = false
options.compilerArgs << '-Xshare:on'
}
```

but I get

```
Cause: error: invalid flag: -Xshare:on
```

I CAN add

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xshare:on
```

to gradle.properties to get the daemon to use CDS (I believe, anyway).

Is there a way to get Gradle/java 11 to use CDS throughout?

By throughout, I mean not just for the daemon but for the compiler as well?

I have also tried:

```
compileJava.options.fork=true
compileJava.options.forkOptions.jvmArgs << '-Xshare:on'
```

But that doesn't get me anywhere either (and I guess would be slower due to the fork overhead...destroying any speed advantage that CDS might provide?)

Comment: You might also try the gradle forums for that question.

Comment: Isn't CDS auto-enabled according to the docs? https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/vm/class-data-sharing.html#GUID-0260F857-A70E-4399-A1DF-A5766BE33285

Comment: @tkruse: true, it seems but the archive is only generated if you use the installer. hmmm. The link you gave explictly says to NOT use -Xshare:on in production. Thanks for enlightening me!